# how to parse a xml with html content as value in java/groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I need to convert the below xml to json with the nested HTML content intact.

```xml
<example>
    <value attribute="value">some treatment <b>plant</b> with bio chemicals</value>
</example>
```

To Json

```json
{
  "example": {
    "value": {
      "attribute": "value",
      "content": "some treatment <b>plant</b> with bio chemicals"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do it with all popular libaraies like jackson, org.json, json-simple , JSON-lib. But i could not find a possibly library that can do it out of the box.

Can i get an idea if there are any possible libraries to do this if not any way to achieve this conversion

Comment: It was suggested by @stleary (Author of org.json) that we could wrap the XML content which had mark up with CDATA
`<example><value attribute="value"><![CDATA[some treatment <b>plant</b> with bio chemicals]]></value></example>`
But that is not an option. As the xml feed is not in my control.

Comment: You don't have XML with embedded HTML, you have malformed XML. HTML is not valid XML and can't be parsed correctly by an XML parser. Which means that if you want to put HTML inside XML you will have to encode the <, >, and " symbols. Your example doesn't do that. Any 'solution' that you might come up with will only ever work by accident.

Comment: @jurgen yeah, I agree. But the malformed XML is what I have to parse and groovy had a good way to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `XmlSlurper` from `Groovy` to parse the XML (which internally uses `SAX` Parser which is light weight). In java, we can do the same, but groovy GPath made it even easier.

```
def parseXMLWithMarkup() {
    String xmlWithMarkup = """
    <example>
        <value attribute="value">some treatment <b>plant</b> with bio chemicals</value>
    </example>
    """;
    example = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlWithMarkup)
    textInsideValueWithMarkup = example.childNodes().findAll { it.name() == 'value' }.collect {
        it.children().collect { child ->
            if (child instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node) {
                return "<" + child.name() + ">" + child.text() + "</" + child.name() + ">"
            } else {
                return child
            }
        }.join('')
    }
    println textInsideValueWithMarkup[0]
}
```

We can access XML values with

```
example.value.text()
```

we can access XML attribute values with

```
example.value.@attribute.text()
```